# Telnet to a specific port on my ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, tcp, telnet, aws-security-group

I need to telnet to my ec2 instance on port `2222`. I have included it in the security groups with source as `Anywhere` and `Custom TCP Rule`. It is a 64 bit Linux Machine. I am able to connect via port `22` but when I try with `2222`, it shows `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. Also I need to skip the login/password prompt if connected successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port the Telnet server is listening on in it's configuration file.

Comment: You mean /etc/services?

Comment: It depends on what Linux distro you are running. Check in `/etc/inetd.conf` or `/etc/xinetd.d/telnet`